# Prevent ``/etc/profile.d`` from being sourced on login

Tags: linux, bash, login, profile

I just noticed my environment is behaving erratically because at
some point this alias got introduced in
`/etc/profile.d/vim.sh`:

```
$ command -v vim
alias vim='__vi_internal_vim_alias'
```

Looking through the files in `/etc/profile.d`, they’re of no
use to me as everything I need is already taken care of in my
`.bashrc`. As a consequence, Bash starts out in an
unnecessarily polluted state after login. I’d like Bash to
completely ignore the directory and just execute `.bashrc`.
However, as the manpage states it will blindly source everything
in that path before it continues with user controlled rc files.

This is a corporate environment so I have no control over the OS
just my user account.

There’s an option `--noprofile` but I can’t seem to get it
added to passwd:

```
$ chsh
Changing shell for philipp.
New shell [/bin/bash]
> /bin/bash --noprofile
chsh: "/bin/bash --noprofile" does not exist
```

Through SSH I could add `bash --noprofile` manually but that
becomes tedious as I have dozens if not hundreds of SSH
connections over the course of a regular workday.

It would be ok if I could just make Bash forget those settings at
the top of `.bashrc` and then continue with a clean environment.
What I would prefer to avoid is having to play whack-a-mole with
whatever definitions `/etc/profile.d` might possibly add on all
the systems I’m using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be out of luck.  `chsh` restricts the shells you can select to those listed in `/etc/shells`, and you can't specify command-line parameters.

The only thing you could look into is to try the other shells listed in `/etc/shells`, in case they don't read `/etc/profile.d`, but I'd be surprised if that worked.  You could also try `unalias -a` at the top of your profile script to clear out all defined aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint "Through SSH I could add bash --noprofile manually". I found this can be added to the local ~/.ssh/config file, which makes it transparent, to avoid the "manually ... tediuous" part. E.g.,

```
# ~/.ssh/config

host myserver
hostname myserver.domain.com
user myname
# Uncomment to choose whether to use login shell or not.
#RemoteCommand bash --login
#RemoteCommand bash --noprofile
RemoteCommand bash
RequestTTY yes
```

Further details at https://superuser.com/questions/1224938/ssh-host-is-a-login-shell-but-ssh-host-command-is-not